# KafkaAdminClient() got error "KafkaConnectionError: KafkaConnectionError: socket disconnected"?

Tags: python, apache-kafka

The following python code got error when creating an instance of `KafkaAdminClient`.

```
from kafka.admin import KafkaAdminClient, NewTopic


admin_client = KafkaAdminClient(
    bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers, 
    client_id='test', 
    security_protocol="SSL"
)
```

got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KafkaConnectionError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-edd53455dcb0> in <module>()
      4 admin_client = KafkaAdminClient(
      5     bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers,
----> 6     client_id='test', security_protocol="SSL"
      7 )
      8 

/apps/external/4/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/admin/client.py in __init__(self, **configs)
    216 
    217         self._closed = False
--> 218         self._refresh_controller_id()
    219         log.debug("KafkaAdminClient started.")
    220 

/apps/external/4/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/admin/client.py in _refresh_controller_id(self)
    271             future = self._send_request_to_node(self._client.least_loaded_node(), request)
    272 
--> 273             self._wait_for_futures([future])
    274 
    275             response = future.value

/apps/external/4/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/admin/client.py in _wait_for_futures(self, futures)
   1340 
   1341                 if future.failed():
-> 1342                     raise future.exception  # pylint: disable-msg=raising-bad-type

KafkaConnectionError: KafkaConnectionError: socket disconnected
```

However, the following code runs without any error.

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    group_id='test', 
    bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers, 
    security_protocol="SSL")
print(consumer.topics())
```

Comment: Hi ca9163d9, have you resolved this? I am getting the same issue. Please let me know the solution in case you have resolved it.